# How to write mock gps provider affect whole system apps

Tags: android, gps

I see that in market there are many mock location application that apply for whole system. (it means when we use google map, uber ...) it will display new location.

I have followed some tutorials. Here is my sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationManager mLocationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLocationManager  = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        setupMockLocations(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        setupMockLocations(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        setupMockLocations(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

    }

       private void setupMockLocations(final String providerName) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (; ; ) {
                mLocationManager.addTestProvider(providerName, false, //requiresNetwork,
                        false, // requiresSatellite,
                        false, // requiresCell,
                        false, // hasMonetaryCost,
                        false, // supportsAltitude,
                        false, // supportsSpeed, s
                        false, // upportsBearing,
                        Criteria.POWER_LOW, // powerRequirement
                        Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); // accuracy

                mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(providerName, true);
                location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                location.setAccuracy(1);
                location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());

                Method locationJellyBeanFixMethod = null;
                try {
                    locationJellyBeanFixMethod = Location.class.getMethod("makeComplete");
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (locationJellyBeanFixMethod != null) {
                    try {
                        locationJellyBeanFixMethod.invoke(location);
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation(providerName, location);


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.e("print", "mocking " + providerName);
            }

        }
    }).run();
}


}
```

But looks like this code doesn't work. (it should display my `sampleLocation` on Google Map instead of current location). I have faked both `GPS_PROVIDER` `NETWORK_PROVIDER` and `PASSIVE_PROVIDER` also. Please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

*How to write mock gps provider affect whole system apps*

It already affects the whole system and it does work. But conditions could change the result. For example in your case,

When you call `setupMockLocations(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` GPS provider caches your fake location. But at this time(or later), if any other app(s) makes location request for GPS and receives fresh GPS location, then your fake location will be overridden.

Your code is correct, but just needs to call `setupMockLocations(...);` periodically to prevent above situation.

This sample works for me, please consider steps

```
public class SampleMocker {

    private int mPeriod = 2 * 1000;
    private Location mMockLocation;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    public SampleMocker(Context context){
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        mMockLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        mLocationManager.addTestProvider(GPS_PROVIDER, false, false, false, 
        false, false, true, true, 0, 5);
        mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(GPS_PROVIDER, true);
    }

    private void start(){
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mMockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                    mMockLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
                }

                mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation(GPS_PROVIDER, mMockLocation);

                mHandler.postDelayed(this, mPeriod);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This code periodically sets mock location at each 2 sec. `private int mPeriod = 2 * 1000;`

You should adjust period time for your usage. Because if other app(s) may make location request with lower period. Then your mock location will not appear so often.

For test : while running this code, open Google Maps and **do not use High Accuracy**, set Device Only mode.

Comment: I have changed my code. I have periodically call `setupMockLocation` but it still not work. maybe something else wrong ?

Comment: What's happening when you leave from your app ? You should run relevant code in service because after switching to Google Maps(or other any), your activity(and mock locations) will stop then Google Maps receive fresh location.

Comment: when I leave my app, thread still run periodically for mocking location (I have checked by printing log).

Comment: thanks so much. it's work :D I just have a small question, I hide `mock location setting` for all apps (using Xposed framework). So when I run above code, I meet an exception: `Requires ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION secure setting`. It looks like android uses some apps for checking mock location and in fact I shouldn't hide this. Do you know which app I shouldn't hide ? thanks